# Is there a way to use the builder pattern in an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I was trying to represent shapes rectangle and oval, with flexibility to eventually add more shapes. So I write an abstract class AShape. In this abstract class, I also want to abstract field setters such as color, width, height, and position.

My first thought is to do the builder pattern, but I know that one has to instantiate the class in order to be able to use the builder, and you can't instantiate an abstract class. Which means I have to do it in the concrete classes, but then that's duplicated code. Is there another pattern that I can use, or is there a way that I can get around this?

Comment: The builder p. is typically used to improve readibility when instantiating classes with a large number of attributes some of which are optional. That doesn't sound like your case.

Comment: Hm okay, thank you. I guess I can just do a bunch of setters in the abstract class and it would be fine, then.

Comment: Prefer making all fields final. Put the common fields in AShape, which has a protected constructor. If you use a builder, have one for each concrete class, but move the common stuff into an abstract builder all builders are subclasses of.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can and as you say produces code more readable and with less repetition:

```
public abstract class AShape {

    private final String color;

    private final int width;

    private final int height;

    private final int position;

    public AShape(String color, int width, int height, int position) {
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }
}

public class Rectangle extends AShape {

    private final int l1;

    private final int l2;

    public Rectangle(String color, int width, int height, int position, int l1, int l2) {
        **super(color, width, height, position);**
        this.l1 = l1;
        this.l2 = l2;
    }

    public int getL1() {
        return this.l1;
    }

    public int getL2() {
        return this.l2;
    }
}
```

As you see you can use the constructor in the child class, although you will never be able to instantiate AShape since it is abstract.